# Computing an integral in $R^n$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this problem which should be easy, but I can't compute it no matter what I try.
The integral has the form 
$$\int_{\Omega}\sum_j b_jx^2_j dx$$
where $\Omega=\{\sum_j x^2_j/a_j^2<1\}$ is a  hyperellipsoid. I tried making a substitution for ellipsoid-like coordinates, $x_j=a_js_j$ where $s_j$ are the standard spherical coordinates in $R^n$, but in the resulting integral I cannot produce anything I can integrate.

I also tried to use the Gauss-Stokes Theorem, creating the vector $F=(b_jx_j^3/3)_j$ for which $divF=\sum_j b_jx^2_j$, but again the surface integral is just terrible.

So my questions are:
-Is there a straightforward change of variables for these type of integrals? I don't think so...
-Is there a theorem that I can employ? Maybe using a differential form... Meaning if I could rewrite the form $\sum_j b_jx^2_j dx$ as dw, then I could turn it into a surface integral using Stokes's theorem.

Any directions on this? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: **Stokes's**, not "Stoke's".

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$x_j=a_j u_j\qquad(u_1^2+\ldots +u_n^2\leq1)\ .$$The Jacobian then is given by $J:=\prod_{j=1}^n a_j$. Let $B_n$ be the unit ball in ${\mathbb R}^n$. Then
$$\int_\Omega \sum_jb_j x_j^2 {\rm d}(x)=J\int_{B_n}\sum_j b_j a_j^2\, u_j^2\>{\rm d}(u)\ .$$
Therefore it remains to compute the integral
$$\int_{B_n}u_1^2\>{\rm d}(u)={1\over n}\int_{B_n}|u|^2\>{\rm d}(u)={1\over n}\int_0^1r^2\cdot \omega_{n-1} r^{n-1}dr={\omega_{n-1}\over n(n+2)}\ ,$$
where $\omega_{n-1}$ denotes the surface of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere. It follows that
$$\int_\Omega \sum_jb_j x_j^2 {\rm d}(x)={\omega_{n-1}\over n(n+2)}J\sum_j b_j a_j^2\ .$$